# How to extract a .zip file in Unity?

Tags: unity-dash, jar

Simple question: how do you unzip or extract .zip archives/files in Ubuntu 12.04 Unity?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to simply click it with right mouse button and choose "Extract here".

Comment: It doesn't give me that option

Comment: Could you post a screenshot please?

Comment: It would be much better if you could add screenshots of the steps..

Comment: @It's Willem Maybe it's because you have Ubuntu 12.04. Newest version is 14.04.

Comment: You could quite easily update for free

Comment: @heemayl  My system language is not english, so I don't think they could help anybody.

Comment: Version 14.04 is free too and it is LTS version as well, Here is the link. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu through Crouton on a Chromebook so upgrading the release would break it. I would install it if I could. Also It won't let me take screenshots so I I can't post one. When I right-click the .zip file there is no option saying extract here or extract to. Maybe it's because I'm using thunar instead of the default?

Comment: I can confirm now that Thunar is not the problem.

Comment: @It's Willem Can you try from nautilus then?

Comment: I did it does not work there either

Comment: @It'sWillem Weird... Eventually, you can extract zip files from terminal. There must be some way to get those options into you file manager.

Comment: @Jacajack What is the command to extract zips?

Comment: I have the links in my answer

Comment: @It'sWillem You can use `unzip yourfile.zip -d destination_directory`, but first you may need to install it by `sudo apt-get install unzip`.

Comment: I worked! Only downside is that when I use the command without specifying a directory to place the new folder in using -d it will extract into my home folder instead of into the folder that the .zip file I extrated was already in. Thanks!

Comment: @It'sWillem I think you can use `$(pwd)` istead of full path, it'll replace it with your current path, so remember to be in destination folder when running this command.

Answer (score 0):

You can just right click and press "Extract Here" to your desired location. Hope this helps!

UPDATE: This could help. Upvote if it helps please.

[How to extract zip file to specific folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520546/how-to-extract-zip-file-to-specific-folder)

OR

[How to unzip a zip file from the Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86849/how-to-unzip-a-zip-file-from-the-terminal)

Comment: It won't let me do that

Comment: It would be much better if you could add screenshots of the steps..

Comment: I currently don't have Ubuntu installed

Comment: @Apad121 So what?

Comment: So I can't exactly post screen shots easily

Comment: @It's Willem does my post help?

Answer (score 0):

In Unity, you can right click on the .zip file you want to open. Then select either:

A) "Open with Archive Manager" (the default action, and allows you to extract the files wherever you want them -- drag and drop), or

B) toward the bottom of the menu, select "Extract Here."

If you select *Extract Here*, the contents will appear in a new folder, but in the same folder where the .zip file is located.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It would be much better if you could add screenshots of the steps..

Comment: I don't have ether of those options

Answer (score 0):

First open terminal and install the unzip by using:

> sudo apt-get install unzip

now navigate to the folder where the file is and open a terminal there by doing this in the terminal:

- `cd /home/user_name/path_to_file/` or`cd ~/path_to_file`
- run `ls` to make sure your in the right folder and if you are your will see the file listed

Then type the following in the terminal

> **unzip** name_of_file.zip

See `man unzip` for more information